# How to create 'Nested List' and display in HTML format

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xquery

In the below example we are trying to convert into seprate paragraph using 'XSLT 1.0' and display in the browser as a 'Nested List':

Can anyone help.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTENT_LIST>
<CONTENT>A. TSS Sunda Strait</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>1. Vessel Reporting Points</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>a) Southbound Reporting Line :</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>1) Crossing Latitude 05° 45’ S for ship from the Northern Part of Jawa Sea.<BR/>2) Crossing Longitude 105° 55’ E for ship from Eastern Part of Jawa Sea.</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>b) Northbound Reporting Line :</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>1) Crossing Latitude 06° 00’ S for ship from Southern Part of SundaStrait.<BR/>2) Crossing Longitude 105° 43.00’ E for ship from Lampung Bay</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>2. Precautionary Area Reporting Points</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>a) Westbound Vessel Reporting Points : 05° 54.00’ S – 105° 53.00’ E<BR/>b) Eastbound Vessel Reporting Points : 05° 52.50’ S – 105° 47.20’ E</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>3. Radio Broadcast VHF Channel 22 and 68 SUNDAREP</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>B. TSS Lombok Strait</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>1. Vessel Reporting Points</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>a) Northbound Vessel :</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>1. 08° 54.65’ S – 115° 43.48’ E<BR/>2. 08° 19.42’ S – 115° 53.96’ E</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>b) Southbound Vessel :</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>1. 08° 53.36’ S – 115° 39.02’ E<BR/>2. 08° 18.29’ S – 115° 51.18’ E</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>2. Reporting Points Southern Precaution Area</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>a) Westbound Points : 08° 38.58’ S – 115° 51.82’ E<BR/>b) Eastbound Points : 08° 37.40’ S – 115° 40.02’ E</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>3. Reporting Points Nortthern Precaution Area</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>a) Westbound Points : 08° 26.53’ S – 115° 56.15’ E<BR/>b) Eastbound Points : 08° 24.94’ S – 115° 44.35’ E</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>4. Radio Broadcast VHF Channel 68 and 16 LOMBOKREP</CONTENT>
<CONTENT>C. Format for Ship Reporting System in Traffic Separation Scheme (TSS) at Sunda Strait and Lombok Strait</CONTENT>
</CONTENT_LIST>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<CONTENT_LIST>
<P STYLE="margin-left:0px">A. TSS Sunda Strait</P>
<P STYLE="margin-left:10px">1. Vessel Reporting Points</P>
<P STYLE="margin-left:20px">a) Southbound Reporting Line :</CONTENT>
<P STYLE="margin-left:30px">1) Crossing Latitude 05° 45’ S for ship from the Northern Part of Jawa Sea.</P>
<P STYLE="margin-left:30px">2) Crossing Longitude 105° 55’ E for ship from Eastern Part of Jawa Sea.</P>
<P STYLE="margin-left:20px">b) Northbound Reporting Line :</P>
<P STYLE="margin-left:30px">1) Crossing Latitude 06° 00’ S for ship from Southern Part of SundaStrait.</P>
<P STYLE="margin-left:30px">2) Crossing Longitude 105° 43.00’ E for ship from Lampung Bay</P>
<P STYLE="margin-left:10px">2. Precautionary Area Reporting Points</P>
    ....................
</CONTENT_LIST>
```

***Expected Image reference:***

[image]

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/CONTENT_LIST">
    <xsl:for-each select="CONTENT/text()">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference Linke#** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniTD/1

Comment: Are you sure that you want this kind of HTML-output. Seems to me you really need nested OL-lists. What did you try (besides the xslt that you posted) until now to get that @STYLE attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The output you show is not really "nested". If you want to handle this by adjusting the margin, then you could simply examine the beginning of each line - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CONTENT_LIST">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="CONTENT">
            <xsl:variable name="indent">
                <xsl:variable name="txt" select="translate(., '23456789bcdefghi', '11111111aaaaaaaa')" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with($txt, '1. ')">10</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with($txt, 'a) ')">20</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="starts-with($txt, '1) ')">30</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <P STYLE="margin-left:{$indent}px">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </P>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes there will be at most 9 consecutive items in each list. If there can be more, you will need to adjust the $txt variable to translate more characters and the tests to look for double-digit numbers as well.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your suggestion, but here level sequence could be change then will not be work, In that case only will be work fine. Please suggest!

Comment: See 1., 2., 3., ...etc. in the attached image output refence under the item 'B.'

Comment: If the structure is not known in advance, then you need some rules to determine the structure. I don't know what such rules might be - and in their absence the problem is not well-defined.

Comment: In the attached image output reference is final output which we required.

Comment: An example does not establish rules.